# Why is python's BaseHTTPServer an old-style class?

Tags: python, python-2.x, httpserver

Is there any reason python's `BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer` is an old-style class?

```
>>> import BaseHTTPServer
>>> type(BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer)
classobj
```

I ask because I want to use `super` in a class that inherits from `HTTPServer` and can't.  There is a workaround:

```
class MyHTTPServer(HTTPServer,object):
    ...
```

Does this workaround have any hidden 'gotchas'?

Comment: Which Python version?

Comment: @LutzHorn: Python 3 has only new-style classes, so 2.X.

Comment: Blender got it right; 2.7.2 though.  I should probably update to 2.7.6.  fwiw, I'm using `six` for this module, so it will be py3-compatible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[According to Steve Holden](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/539455-construct-new-old-style-classes-build-extension-types),

```
... it was easier to leave them as they were than risk
introducing incompatibilities.
```

The problem was corrected in Python3, where all classes are new-style classes.

---

Nowadays, we see only the advantages of new-style classes, and we are accustomed to programming in ways that are compatible with new-style. However, back when classic classes were the norm, there could have been code like this:

```
def __str__():
    return "I'm Classic"

class Classic: pass

c = Classic()
c.__str__ = __str__
print(c)
```

which prints

```
I'm Classic
```

However, if the classic class were changed to be new-style, then this method of defining special methods *on instances* would be broken:

```
class New(object): pass
n = New()
n.__str__ = __str__
print(n)
```

prints

```
<__main__.New object at 0xb746ad4c>
```

With new-style classes, special methods such as `__str__` **must** be defined in the class (or in the MRO) of the object for it to affect the object. That is not the case with old-style classes.

Since Python2 is intended to be backwards-compatible, differences such as this prevent Python2 from changing classic classes in the standard lib to new-style.

Comment: Huh, nice work... you must have encyclopedic knowledge of the python list.  I'm happy to accept this as is, but if you have any thoughts on the 'gotchas' side it would be helpful.